# Python Return Index from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

Trying to find the index value of the user's input in a list of letters (The alphabet). Essientially returning a list of indexes from given list.

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
words = input("Type something: ").upper()
print (list(words))
print (list(alphabet))
#Substring not found, 
print (alpha.index(words))
```

Comment: alphabet != alpha. You should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

return a `result` list with index of `words` in `alphabet` :

```
words = "nice".upper()
result = [alphabet.index(i) for i in words]
result # [13, 8, 2, 4]
```

however if you want real alphabet index you can add 1 to all list elements.

Comment: Thanks! That helps alot. I really do not understand the "i for i in x" thing

Comment: @cparks10 , It's a list comprehension , I suggest you read lists and loops in python tutorial for better understanding of whats going on here!

Comment: I definitely will! So if I wanted to go the other way, and give an index and wanted to print the numbers what would it look like?